# Почему в современном болгарском языке нет ни одного «славянского» падежа?

Tags: старославянский

Как случилось, что «древнеболгарский» язык, считающийся наиболее близким к «старославянскому», в своем современном варианте -болгарском языке- не имеет ни одного «славянского» падежа?

Answer (score 3):

В болгарском языке имеются остаточные падежные формы у личных местоимений: краткая форма — ще го видя (вин., я его увижу), да му дам (дат., чтобы дать ему); полная форма — при него има вода (род., у него есть вода), на него е съдено (дат., ему суждено) и у вопросительных местоимений: Кого виждаш? (Кого ты видишь?) и На кого е съдено? (кому суждено?). Собственные имена существительные очень часто имеют форму звательного падежа, например, Иване, Петре, жено (жена моя!). Есть падежные флексии и в словах, употреблённых в некоторых фразеологизмах (чаще всего славянского корня), напр. «Слава Богу!», совпадающее с русским.

Comment: Очень хорошо, Ашан, и спасибо за Ваш добротный ответ!

А то почти уже стало нормой в мой адрес (у меня в помощниках по части словообразования часто бывает друг, который недавно только зарегистрировался, и которого зачем-то быстро забанили. Он филолог, преподает и т.д.) начинать с упреков или личностных оценок. В который раз убеждаюсь, что еще "многие из нас" нуждаются в элементарном воспитании. 
Увы...

Comment: ...Скажите, приведенный Вами пример можно считать свидетельством того, что в современном болгарском языке действительно нет ни одного славянского падежа? (речь, конечно, не о частичных явлениях (флексиях, остаточных формах...), а полноценном спряжении как принципе в языке).

Comment: Федя, а вот путать склонение и спряжение — это уж совсем неприлично. И куда только ваш друг-филолог смотрит... ))))

Comment: Я тоже вздрогнул.

Answer (score 3):

В совр. болгарском языке действительно нет склонений, т.е. окончания  имён (кроме личных местоимений и вокатива) не меняются, именные словосочетания формируются с помощью предлогов, в отличие, например, от английского и шведского языков, в болгарском не бывает беспредложного косвенного дополнения: аз дадох книгата на Наташа (ср. англ. "I gave Natasha the book", шв. "jag gav Natasja boken").

http://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=11882.0

Это доказывает, что грамматика старославянского ему чужда. В науке господствует мнение, что в «среднеболгарский» период в языке  теряются  грамматические категории существительных – падежи (в связи с фонетическими изменениями), усложняется глагольная система, появляются синтетические конструкции, не зафиксированные ни в одном из славянских письменных источников, а вслед за этим, уже практически в наше время, болгары отказываются и от этого, упрощая громоздкий аналитизм системы времен. Не думаю, что это так.

Есть другое мнение: современный болгарский язык сформировался совсем недавно, в 20-м веке,  выдавив из своей основы все лишние грамматический формы, навязываемые по традиции книжниками и лингвистами на протяжение  долгого времени, и оставив лишь те, которые необходимы и достаточны для обслуживания коммуникативных потребностей. Явно, что предки болгар НИКОГДА не говорили на языке, похожем на церковнославянский: вполне усвоив насаждаемую лексику, они так и не смогли понять чуждую для них категорию падежа. Древние же грамматики и летописцы, более или менее усвоившие данную грамматическую категорию, со временем под давлением народного языка стали терять развитый навык и в конце концов, после периода неустойчивого употребления, окончательно потеряли его. То же самое произошло и со сложными аналитическими формами, которые начали насаждать в болгарскую языковую систему. Произведения классических болгарских писателей  зафиксировали и донесли до нашего времени не языковую традицию староболгарского языка, а свидетельство неудавшейся попытки внедрения искусственных грамматических правил, противоречащих сложившимся к тому времени языковым навыкам и привычкам.

В основе письменного современного болгарского языка лежат восточные диалекты, а произношение представляет собой сочетание восточных и западных диалектов (образование диалектов главным образом связано с постоянной миграцией древних болгарских племен, с покорением Болгарии Византийской империей, в ХIII веке венгры силой вывезли большое число болгар с Дунайской равнины в Трансильванию (Зибенбурген) и продали в рабство, затем вторжение турок, часть населения была истреблена, кто-то бежал в Балканские и Родопские горы, значительная часть северо-западной Болгарии утеряла свою самобытность после неудачных восстаний в Тырново и  в городе Чипровци).

Поэтому нельзя сказать, что  старославянский – основа совр. болгарского языка, а язык утратил грамматич. категорию падежей. Их, видимо, там НЕ БЫЛО.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила!
Очень полезный для меня материал.
Я рад, что подозрения мои в отношении "болгарских древностей" подтверждаются, в том числе, благодаря историческим выкладкам.

Думаю, опираясь на это, смогу уже вести дальше разговор собственно о феномене церковно-славянского и миссии Кирилла с Мефодием.

Comment: почитайте это:  http://www.bci-moscow.ru/ru/Education/Bulgarian/history_bulgarian_language/  
и это:    http://www.chronologia.org/dcforum/DCForumID2/13950.html

Comment: Спасибо и Вам - http://goo.gl/YK3c3x

Comment: Очень однобокий (хотя и с претензией на объективность) ответ. Исходя из вашего ответа можно сделать вывод, что болгарский вообще сам по себе и с другими славянскими языками не связан. Но вот беда, в болгарских диалектах косвенные падежи в той или иной форме сохранились...

Answer (score 0):

> Как случилось, что «древнеболгарский» язык, считающийся наиболее близким к «старославянскому», в своем современном варианте -болгарском языке- не имеет ни одного «славянского» падежа?

Потому, что они пропали.

Comment: Это как с малазийским боингом, помните?
Почему он не долетел до места посадки? Потому, что его сбили.


Так, почему же падежи в болгарском не сохранились?